# Custom embedded player in Facebook posts

Tags: facebook, audio, share

I have built an audio sharing application (pretty similar to soundcloud.com, but focused on a niche and just one country). I'd like to enable people to hear the tracks directly from Facebook, like they can do it with eg. Spotify. 
I am having a trouble with getting development docs on how to do that.

Cheers,

Pablox

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Deep-integration with Facebook (such as Spotify have done) is done via the Open Graph APIs, the beta documentation is covered here: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph

If you just want users to be able to embed a player in posts/likes of your content, any app can do this with the use of meta tags on the pages, and this is covered under 'Attaching Audio and Video Data' on the [Open Graph documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/)

Comment: open graph helps you to determine the title and other things rendered by Facebook. But it is not working to show an embedded audio player.